# Need assitance understanding Sardinas-Patterson algorithm (Algorithm and example provided)

Tags: algorithm, math

I am having difficulty understanding Sardinas- Patterson algorithm from the below slide:

[image]

How do we get C1 and C2???

I also got this information from the internet:

The algorithm is finite because all dangling suffixes added to the list are suffixes of a finite set of codewords, and a dangling suffix can be added at most once.

- { 0, 01, 11 }. The codeword 0 is a prefix of 01, so add the dangling suffix 1. { 0, 01, 11, 1 }. The codeword 0 is a prefix of 01, but the dangling suffix 1 is already in the list; the codeword 1 is a prefix of 11, but the dangling suffix 1 is already in the list. There are no other dangling suffixes, so conclude that the set is uniquely decodable.
- { 0, 01, 10 }. The codeword 0 is a prefix of 01, so add the dangling suffix 1 to the list. { 0, 01, 10, 1 }. The codeword 1 is a prefix of 10, but the dangling suffix 0 is a codewords. So, conclude that the code is not uniquely decodeable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm) is a great explanation

The C in your slide correspond to the S<sub>i</sub> from the wiki article.

Here is description from me:

The important operation is taking two strings from C and if one of them is a prefix to the other you and to record the suffix that is left when the prefix is removed.
This is how C<sub>1</sub> is obtained.

With the following C<sub>2</sub>, C<sub>3</sub>, etc.
You again want to look for words from C which are prefixes to words from C<sub>i</sub> and take the remaining suffix, but you also want to look at the words from C_i and remove and words from C which are prefixes. C<sub>(i+1)</sub> is the union of those sets.

As soon as some C<sub>i</sub> contains a word from C you know the code is not uniquely decodeable.

So:

C = 1, 011, 01110, 1110, 10011

C<sub>1</sub> = 110 (because (1)110 is in C), 0011 (because (1)0011 is inC), 10 (because (011)10 is in C)

C<sub>2</sub> = {10 (because (1)10 is in C<sub>1</sub>), 0 (because (1)0 is in C<sub>1</sub>)} union { 011, because (10)011 is in C }

Comment: THANK YOU! EXACTLY WHAT I WAS AFTER! an explanation!

Comment: @Petar Ivanov: How was the word `011101110011` decided? I understand how to get c1, c2,...,ci but how did they get this word `011101110011`?

Answer (score 5):

C1 is found by seeing if any code word in C is a prefix of any other code word in C, if it is then the suffix is added to the set C1. e.g. 1 is a prefix of 1110 and hence you get the suffix 110 which is added to C1.

For C2, first you check to see if the code words in C is a prefix of any other code word in C1 if it is then make a set of all the "dangling suffix" , you then check if C1 is a prefix of any code words in C if it is then again make a set of all the "dangling suffix". Then you take the union of those two sets which results in C2.

Hopefully that kinda made sense.

Comment: Btw for C1, where do they get "10" from?

Comment: 011 in C is a prefix of 01110 in C therefore you get a suffix of 10

Answer (score 4):

The sets C1 and C2 correspond to S1 and S2 in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm#Precise_description_of_the_algorithm).

Specifically, C1 is the set of words that can remain after we take a single word from C and remove some its prefix that is also in C.

For C2 we have the words that can remain after we take a word from C and remove a prefix from C1, or after we take a word from C1 and remove a prefix from C.

If we wanted to compute C3, we would take the words that can remain after we take a word from C and remove some its prefix that is in C2, and the words that can remain after we take a word from C2 and remove some its prefix that is in C.

Thus, C3 would be: {[empty word], 0, 011, 10, 11, 1110}. It contains the empty word, so the algorithm halts and determines that C is not uniquely decodable.